# Inline Tex Math expressions positioning in Anki

Tags: math-mode, html, anki

I'm not exactly familiar with how [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/) processes the inline math expressions, but the developer advised me to ask this question on a Tex discussion platform:

The problem is that the rendered formulas are always placed a bit too high in the text. Like this:

[image]

How can I change this?

**Edit:**

> All Anki does is combine the text on your card with the prefix and
>   postfix in the deck options and send it to LaTeX, so if you're having
>   layout problems you'll need to ask on a LaTeX forum.

The only related settings I could find are the LaTex header and footer:

Header:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\special{papersize=3in,5in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}
\scriptsize
```

Footer:

```
\end{document}
```

Comment: According to the [Anki documentation - Advanced: LaTeX](http://ankisrs.net/docs/AddItems.html#_advanced_latex), Anki converts (La)TeX to PNG using `dvipng`, and even the documentation example shows the alignment you present. As such, I don't think this has anything to do with (La)TeX. It is perhaps the browsers default to insert images at the baseline the surrounding browser text.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to place the text you want aligned in the LaTeX environment as well. i.e. `[latex]$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\cdot x^n$ \sf mit dem...[/latex]`

Comment: This looks 'off topic' to me, as Werner says.

Comment: I agree that this is off-topic.  It is to do with the baseline adjustment for placing the image.  You would need to find out the baseline for the text in the image relative to the bounding box (I guess, in principle, this would be information provided by TeX so that might be on-topic if you asked just that) and then pass those parameters to whatever-it-is that generates the HTML to adjust the placement of the image.

Comment: The problem is not the LaTeX layout, though. It is the *relative* layout between the generated image and the surrounding text.  The kind of "layout problem" that we could help you with would be one that was internal to the LaTeX, say if you wanted the subscript to be left-aligned on the summation.

Comment: @user8823741 I had exactly the same problem, and found the answer! Go to Browse -> Mark a card -> Click "...Cards" button. Now in the styling box add this css `img{vertical-align:middle;}` Works like a charm :D:D